# Кодировка JSON в UTF-8

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

Подскажите пожалуйста, как меняется кодировка в строке JSON консоли Intellij idea?

Мой код.

```
    package reversbot.services;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.vk.api.sdk.client.TransportClient;
import com.vk.api.sdk.client.VkApiClient;
import com.vk.api.sdk.client.actors.UserActor;
import com.vk.api.sdk.exceptions.ApiException;
import com.vk.api.sdk.exceptions.ClientException;
import com.vk.api.sdk.httpclient.HttpTransportClient;
import com.vk.api.sdk.objects.wall.GetFilter;
import com.vk.api.sdk.objects.wall.responses.GetResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;


@Service

public class VkBot {

    @Value("${APP_ID}")
    int APP_ID;

    @Value("${access_token}")
    String access_token;
    private String jsonString;


    //    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    @PostConstruct

    public void vkb() throws ClientException, ApiException, IOException {

        TransportClient transportClient = new HttpTransportClient();
        VkApiClient vk = new VkApiClient(transportClient);


        UserActor actor = new UserActor(APP_ID, access_token);



        GetResponse getResponse = vk.wall().get(actor)
                .ownerId(-26493942)
                .count(1)
                .offset(5)
                .filter(GetFilter.valueOf("ALL"))
                .execute();

//        getResponse = URLEncoder.encode(getResponse,"UTF-8");

        System.out.println("........FROM HERE.........");
        System.out.println(getResponse);
        System.out.println(".........HERE........");

//          jsonString = String.valueOf(getResponse);
//
//        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
//        VkBot res = mapper.readValue(jsonString,VkBot.class);
//        System.out.println(res);
    }

}
```

В консоле выводятся знаки вопроса, вместо 'text'

"post","reposts":{"count":3,"user_reposted":0},"text":"?????????? ?????????? ????????? ?????? ??????? ??????? ? ????????? ??????? ?? ??????? ???. ?? ???? ??? ????????? ???? ?? ?????????? ????? � ???????......

Comment: Сразу не обратил внимание, но проблема связана с отображением кириллицы в Intellij idea.

Comment: вопрос неактуален уже?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Еще актуален. Я не так давно пользуюсь данной IDE, из- за этого порой не могу понять в чем проблема. Или IDE, или код?

Comment: взыл ваш код из вопроса... пока не получилось воспроизвести ни в ИДЕЕ ни в терминале: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqu3x.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/r46KW.png

Comment: по всей видимости вопрос не в коде(или же не в том коде, который предоставлен в вопросе).. возможно тут дело в настройках

Comment: нужны дополнительные вводные чтобы вам помочь

Comment: System.out.print  тоже выводит только знаки вопроса. Смена кодировки в настройках проблему не устраняет. Действительно, проблема в IDE.

Comment: - если хотите - можете написать в тг мне (он в профиле указан). могу посмотреть что у вас там если сильно надо (в комментах переписываться времени больше займет)

Comment: @bodrovdeni Какая версия JDK используется?

Comment: Использую 18. В дебагере виден, нормальный русский текст, грешу на кодировки.

Comment: @bodrovdeni Поставь версию JDK ниже, например 17 или 14.

Comment: @bodrovdeni Проблему то решил нет?

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh Винду на днях буду переустанавливать, потом посмотрю поможет или нет, обязательно напишу.

Comment: @bodrovdeni Из-за шрифтов винду переустанавливать? Профессионально! :) Ты пробовал версию JDK понизить и указать это в IDE?

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh У меня ноут корпоративный, идёт ребрендинк компании, винда сделана под компанию, сейчас сделали другую.  Заставляют переустанавливать. А так, у меня своя сборка винды, без кириллицы, основной регион и язык USA.